# scatter more than one dataframe in the same plot

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot

I'm using a for cycle to scatter more than one dataframe on a same pd.plot.scatterplot, but everytime the cycle return it print a colorbar. 
How can I have just one colorbar at the end of the cycle?

This is my code

```
if colormap is None: colormap='jet'
f,ax = plt.subplots()
for i, data in enumerate(wells):
    data.plot.scatter(x,y, c=z, colormap=colormap, ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel(x); ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylabel(y); ax.set_ylim(ylim)
ax.legend()
ax.grid()
ax.set_title(title)
```

Comment: what is the type of wells? a dataframe? how many total plots do you want? just one scatterplot?

Comment: it's a dataframe. I want just one plot, exactly ...with all the data on it...

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using figure and adding the axes to the same subplot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# created two dataframes with random values
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(25, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(25, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])
```

And then:

```
fig = plt.figure()
for i, data in enumerate([df1, df2]):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax = data.plot.scatter(x='a', y='b', ax=ax,
                           c='#00FF00' if i == 0 else '#FF0000')

plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting image with two dataframes plotted in one figure]

You can add the labels and other elements as required.

Comment: in this way it plot two colorbars again!

Comment: Okay, let's try this again :) I have updated the snippet so that we have one figure and plot all the scatters to one subplot. Can I also ask you to share a little bit about the data and the plotting library being used? Is it a pandas dataframe? Can you share a few sample rows?

Comment: sorry, can't share data...but they are alla pandas dataframe, no other libraries used in this :)

Comment: You can see my updated answer, with a working example. You can add your labels, grids and axis limits as required.